# jquery animation briefly stutters

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I have a very simple page with a block as such:

```
#block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

jquery code as follows:

```
var block = $('#block');
function changecol() {
    block.animate({width: 100, height: 100}, 300, function() {
        block.animate({width: 50, height: 50}, 300, changecol());
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    block.css('visibility', 'visible');
    changecol();
})
```

So I'm trying to start a chain of callback functions and it's working.
The problem I have is a short pause in the very first animation (during the first block "growth"). It stops for (maybe?) 1.5 seconds and then it will run smoothly.
Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `()` in your second callback:

```
var block = $('#block');

function changecol() {
    block.animate({width: 100, height: 100}, 300, function() {
        // just changecol instead of changecol() here
        block.animate({width: 50, height: 50}, 300, changecol);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    block.css({visibility:'visible'});
    changecol();
});
```

[jsFiddle to prove it](http://jsfiddle.net/7ugep/)

Comment: Jeez it works! Thanks! Could you give me a reason why the `()` causes the lag?

Comment: `changecol` is a REFERENCE to the function `animate` will use as a callback.  `changecol()` EXECUTES the function and uses it's return value (`undefined`) as `animate`'s callback.  `changecol()` will forever keep calling `changecol()` and start infinite animations...  That would explain the lag.

Comment: Thanks once again @cereal77killer!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it only using CSS, No jQuery is needed:

```
#block {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-animation: changecol .5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: changecol .5s infinite;
    -o-animation: changecol .5s infinite;
    animation: changecol .5s infinite;
    background: red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changecol{
    0%   { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
   50%   { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
  100%   { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes changecol{
    0%   { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
   50%   { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
  100%   { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
}
@-o-keyframes changecol{
    0%   { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
   50%   { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
  100%   { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
}
@keyframes changecol{
    0%   { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
   50%   { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
  100%   { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
}
```

Comment: upvoting this because a CSS solution is always better ... the jQuery solution i provided should only be a backup for browsers that do not support animations.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it coud be done in CSS only but I needed to support older browsers somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is multi-tiered. Its a cross of the browser your on, your system specs, even the monitors resolution and refresh rate. As well as the overall animation itself. In your case the animation timing is very very short and the change is subtle as well. So its going to shutter to match the difference in width/height and time given to match the new width/height.

As it has to in that time calculate pixels vs duration.

One way to fix it, is increase the time given, from 300 to something else, a larger number for instance.

Comment: Nope, the lag was increasing together with the animation duration I choose.